# Extracting subset from netCDF file using lat/lon and converting into .csv in R

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a series of nertCDF files containing global data for a particular variable, e.g. tmin/tmax/precipiation/windspeed/relative humuidity/radiation etc. I get the following information when using *nc_open* function in R:

datafile: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpo7zklcmtm3g5r/gfdl_preci.nc?dl=0

File gfdl_preci.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4_CLASSIC):

```
     1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        float prAdjust[lon,lat,time]   
            _FillValue: 1.00000002004088e+20
            missing_value: 1.00000002004088e+20
            comment: includes all types (rain, snow, large-scale, convective, etc.)
            long_name: Bias-Corrected Precipitation
            units: kg m-2 s-1
            standard_name: precipitation_flux

     3 dimensions:
        lon  Size:720
            standard_name: longitude
            long_name: longitude
            units: degrees_east
            axis: X
        lat  Size:360
            standard_name: latitude
            long_name: latitude
            units: degrees_north
            axis: Y
        time  Size:365   *** is unlimited ***
            standard_name: time
            units: days since 1860-1-1 00:00:00
            calendar: standard
            axis: T

    14 global attributes:
        CDI: Climate Data Interface version 1.7.0 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)
        Conventions: CF-1.4
        title: Model output climate of GFDL-ESM2M r1i1p1 Interpolated to 0.5 degree and bias corrected using observations from 1960 - 1999 for EU WATCH project
        CDO: Climate Data Operators version 1.7.0 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)
        product_id: input
        model_id: gfdl-esm2m
        institute_id: PIK
        experiment_id: historical
        ensemble_id: r1i1p1
        time_frequency: daily
        creator: isimip@pik-potsdam.de
        description: GFDL-ESM2M bias corrected impact model input prepared for ISIMIP2.
```

I have been able to read the netCDF file (variables and dimensions) and fragment the time into fields. But, I still need to extract a slice of information based on location (using 4 co-ordinates of a square) e.g., europe. Later, I have to convert the slice into .csv format.

so far I could make up to this step:

```
# load the ncdf4 package
library(ncdf4)

# set path and filename
setwd("D:/netcdf")
ncname <- "gfdl_preci"
ncfname <- paste(ncname, ".nc", sep = "")
dname <- "prAdjust" 

# open a netCDF file
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)
# get longitude and latitude
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lon")
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)

lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lat")
nlat <- dim(lat)
head(lat)

print(c(nlon,nlat))

# get time
time <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time")
time

tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"time","units")
nt <- dim(time)
nt
tunits

# get variable
preci.array <- ncvar_get(ncin,dname)

dlname <- ncatt_get(ncin,"prAdjust","long_name")

dunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"prAdjust","units")

fillvalue <- ncatt_get(ncin,"prAdjust","_FillValue")

dim(preci.array)

# split the time units string into fields
tustr <- strsplit(tunits$value, " ")

tdstr <- strsplit(unlist(tustr)[3], "-")

tmonth = as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[2])

tday = as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[3])

tyear = as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[1])

chron(time, origin = c(tmonth, tday, tyear))
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Can you please post your R code for get this result.

Comment: # load the ncdf4 package
library(ncdf4)

# set path and filename
setwd("D:/netcdf")
ncname <- "gfdl_preci"
ncfname <- paste(ncname, ".nc", sep = "")
dname <- "prAdjust" 

# open a netCDF file
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)

Comment: hi, you made some progress with your problem. It looks like that your question is answered? If so consider to close the question. By the way, how you ask the question is not a good style. People don't appreciated this. Try to make your code example reproducable but remove for the question not relevant information. You can read here about it more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much for kind comment. I apologise for the not being able to present my question in a standard format. Nevertheless, I have been able to read the netCDF file (variables and dimensions) and fragment the time into fields. But, I still need to extract a slice of information based on location (using 4 co-ordinate points of a square) e.g., europe. Later, I have to convert the slice into .csv format.

Answer (score 0):

1.) We don't know your file, but you can get some insides of a netCDF object in R like this:

```
data <- ncvar_get(ncin)
data
```

Or you address the slots directly. You can also try other numbers like 11 or 7, to address other slots on the list object.

```
ncin[[7]]
ncin[[11]]
```

2.) Here is the documentation of the package you use, i think the answer of your problem is somewhere in there:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/ncdf4.pdf

3.) You save information from R in a file like this:

```
write.csv(cbind(lat, lon), "result.csv", row.names=F)
```

Comment: I add how to save it to csv

Answer (score 0):

you can extract point in nc with `library raster`

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

r <- brick("csiromk3.6-rcp45-2010-2099-pr.nc", varname = "pr")
vals <- extract(r, matrix(c(95.46400, 5.40400), ncol = 2))
vals
```

you can write it into csv by convert vals to dataframe

```
vals <- as.data.frame(t(vals),row.names = FALSE)

write.csv(vals, "D:\\ch_2010_2099_rcp45.csv")
```